# Redirect from a method in a class to an action result in a controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a mvc application and when a user is authenticated,
a method is called from  a class to determine the type of user.

I will like to do a redirect to an action result in a controller from a method in a class.

How do i redirect from a method in a class to an action result in a controller?

Comment: post your code, not clear what your asking... are you saying you want your class method to return an ViewAction?

Comment: From a method in a class I want to redirect to a page

Comment: you need to post some code.... ultimately a controller must be in call stack for this to work.

Comment: Why you want redirect to an action in your class?I think you must get type of user in your action and then redirect to action result.

Answer (score 0):

There might be a good reason for why you want to do it this way, but I want to suggest an alternative for you.
I would suggest that you redirect to an action based on the result from a method in a class, rather than doing the redirection in the method itself.

Pseudo-code:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
 var tmp = new YourClass();

if(tmp.UserType().Equals("Admin")
{
    return RedirectToAction("Admin", "Home");
}
if(tmp.UserType().Equals("User"))
{
    return RedirectToAction("User","Home");
}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

First off, I think it's not a good practice to call controller actions from classes like you wish.
Your class will be tightly coupled to an MVC controller.
However it's feasible by doing this:

```
    var context = new RequestContext(
    new HttpContextWrapper(System.Web.HttpContext.Current), 
    new RouteData());
var urlHelper = new UrlHelper(context);
var url = urlHelper.Action("Index", new { OtherParm = "other value" });
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(url);
```

this example comes from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2066351/redirect-asp-net-mvc-page-from-business-logic-class)